# Returns ID's where 2nd columns is not unique.

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL, I am trying to find a formula that finds ID's with exactly the same tagnumbers as a different ID. So for:

```
ID    Tagnumber         
 1    44      
 1    45      
 2    45      
 2    44          
 3    42      
 3    44          
 3    44          
 4    55    
 4    55          
 4    55          
 4    55
```

It should return 1 and 2, because these ID's have a tagnumber composition that is not unique. The order or the amount of tag ID's does not matter, if the same tag id's also exist under a different ID, it should be returned. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select tags, group_concat(id order by id) as ids
from (select id, group_concat(tagnumber order by tagnumber) as tags
      from t
      group by id
     ) i
group by tags
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Getting an error: "unknown column 'tagnumber' in 'field list'"    I checked the column at it should be correct.

Comment: @Dechesne this answer is correct. I interpreted it wrong. Removing my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help Madhur.